# Upload an image tinymce using jbimages plugin

Tags: tinymce, codeigniter-2, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I use the plugin jbimages, everything goes ok but I need to set a defined width for image, width = 600px. Exists a solution?Help me please.Thnx

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width in your css on the pages you upload them? for example if the images are all in a div wrapper , use

```
.wrapper img {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}
```